# NSTextView and highlighting links

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I'm using a `NSTextView` with an `NSAttributedString` to display some links using the `NSLinkAttributeName`. I'm styling those links using the `setLinkTextAttributes:` method of `NSTextView`. However, I would like to give the user a visual feedback when he clicks the link, for example by changing the color of the link while the user pressed down the left mouse button. Is there an easy way to do that or do I have to use `NSTextAttachment`?

Comment: You could always just use a `WebView` instead. Then you can style the links however you like.

Comment: I don't want to use a `WebView` for performance reasons since there are multiple `NSTextView`s visible at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this if you want it to happen on the mouseDown event. If you can wait until the click is completed, then you can do it using the text view delegate method, textView:clickedOnLink:atIndex: to get the index of the clicked on link.  You could then use that index to pass to the text storage method, attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange: to get the range of the link and finally, use setAttributes:range: to make whatever changes you want to the attributes of the link.

If you really need to do it on the mouseDown, then you'll have to subclass the text view and override mouseDown and maybe use something like characterIndexForPoint: to find out whether you've clicked on a link and respond as above.